# If statement with array conditions in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, if-statement, for-loop

This code is a part of the project that i'm currently doing. I want to add 26 into the minus value elements in the array. Here is the simple code that I wrote in bash, but the output is not changing and it showing command not found. can anyone help me please:

```
  declare -a B
  B[0]=5
  B[1]=-11
  B[2]=-14
  B[3]=25

  for((i=0; i<4; i++))do
      if [[ $B{[i]} < 0 ]]; then 
           B[$i] ="(( B[$i] + 26))"
      fi
  done
  echo ${B[@]}
```

Expected Output:

```
  5 15 12 25
```

But the actual output for my code:

```
  Line ##: B[1]: command not found
  Line ##: B[2]: command not found
  5 -11 -14 25
```

Comment: Did you [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) this?

Comment: You can't have a space before or after `=` in an assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Replace it with this :

```
declare -a B
B[0]=5
B[1]=-11
B[2]=-14
B[3]=25

for((i=0; i<4; i++))do
  if (( ${B[i]} < 0 ));then 
       (( B[$i] +=  26 ))
  fi
done
echo ${B[@]}
```